# Deleting Invoice and Bill

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I could not figure out how to delete an Invoice or Bill using qbfc (using version 13).
there is a method to delete a list item but could not find a similar transaction delete method.

Comment: FYI accountants get nervous when people delete transactions rather than voiding them. Make sure this is what your users really want.

Comment: I am integrating invoices and bills from another system, and when they delete it from the original system it has to be deled from QB.I am trying to give them a control screen where they can check and delete the transactions just by clicking a few buttons.

Comment: I am hoping that the system would throw an error if that invoice/bill was paid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `TxnDel` request.

XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="11.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <TxnDelRq>
      <!-- TxnDelType may have one of the following values: ARRefundCreditCard, Bill, BillPaymentCheck, BillPaymentCreditCard, BuildAssembly, Charge, Check, CreditCardCharge, CreditCardCredit, CreditMemo, Deposit, Estimate, InventoryAdjustment, Invoice, ItemReceipt, JournalEntry, PayrollLiabilityAdjustment [PRIVATE], PayrollPriorPayment [PRIVATE], PayrollYearToDateAdjustment [PRIVATE], PurchaseOrder, ReceivePayment, SalesOrder, SalesReceipt, SalesTaxPaymentCheck, TimeTracking, TransferInventory, VehicleMileage, VendorCredit -->
      <TxnDelType>Invoice</TxnDelType> <!-- required -->
      <TxnID>ABCD-1234</TxnID> <!-- required -->
    </TxnDelRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Deleting_%22Transaction%22_Objects_(Invoices,_Journal_Entries,_etc.)
- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks

Should look something like:

```
ITxnDel TxnDelRq= requestMsgSet.AppendTxnDelRq();

//Set field value for TxnDelType
TxnDelRq.TxnDelType.SetValue(ENTxnDelType.tdtARRefundCreditCard);

//Set field value for TxnID
TxnDelRq.TxnID.SetValue("200000-1011023419");

IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
```

Comment: I tought the transaction ID would be the same transaction ID that we recieve from the add message. Looks like it is not. What should we pass as the transaction Id?

Comment: It is. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Because I get a status code of 3000 saying that the transaction does not exists. (I am passing in the returned txn number not the invoice number) The message is: The given object ID "37592" in the field "Transaction id" is invalid.

Comment: You're passing in a TxnNumber, when you should be passing in a TxnID value. Hence the call to .TxnID.SetValue(...) and the error message indicating the error is with the "Transaction id" field. TxnNumber != TxnID

Comment: Yup I see it, I am storing and passing back the TxnNumber, not the TxnID. I have to change that part of integration log and start storing the TxnId for that to work. Thanks a lot Keith.